# How to whitelist unknown domains in blackberry 10 and webworks sdk?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, ripple

I know that to access an external link, one has to whitelist the access path in config.xml.

My problem is that I am unable to use asterisk as the whitelist option. Ripple emulator does not let me do it. My app downloads a number of image links and then display those images. These images could come from any number of sources/ domains. Now how do I mention an intelligent whitelist for this purpose?

My Environment:
BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11
BB10 Simulator
Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

The way you do that is adding this line in the config.xml file:

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="*" />
```

But there's a quirk that renders this option useless whenever you use ajax. From [the docs](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/access_element_834677_11.html):

> *You can specify a wildcard (*) for the uri to whitelist any domain, but only for domains that do not access application APIs and that do not access content through XMLHttpRequest. If the domain requires access to APIs or accesses data through XMLHttpRequest, you must explicitly specify the domain in the uri.*

Comment: thanks Mister Smith for the document link and details provided

Answer (score 1):

As Mister Smith said above, the proper way to 'whitelist' a domain is by adding the wildcard access element to your config.xml

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="*" />
```

You also have the ability to disable all web-security. While this is not the first recommended approach to dealing with cross origin requests, it's sometimes needed, especially when talking to services that use a CDN. To disable all web-security you'll want to add the following to your config.xml

```
<feature id="blackberry.app" >
    <param name="websecurity" value="disable" />
</feature>
```

Lastly, your Ripple issue is something separate from all of this.

Go to manage your Chrome extensions, find Rippe, and check the box that says "Allow access to file URLs", and add the following flag to your Chrome shortcut --allow-access-from-files

Comment: okie. but if I use this option of disabling websecurity then I am afraid that my app might be banned from release on app world?

Comment: You can disable it all, the functionality is provided by the SDK, there's nothing wrong with using it. ;)